# Auto Sort Data Moved by Script

Tags: google-apps-script

My issue is, I have data being moved from one Sheet to another via script when marked "Complete". In the "Completed" sheet is where I want to sort the data. I already have an Autosort script that works only when debugging, not even on edit (tried editing everywhere), Let alone when data is moved to the sheet.

I want to be able to Auto sort whenever data is moved to the new sheet (I don't think its an onEdit function?)

I am not a programmer and I'm fairly new to Google Apps Script. I just dabble into code once in a while because I find it interesting, so I don't even know where to start to get the results I'm looking for.

This is the Auto Sort,

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var sheetNames = ["Complete"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 
sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
  });
}
```

EDIT: I realized I was using a script for multiple sheets. I changed it for one sheet, same issues though.

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Returns");
    var range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 
sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your function to one another

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Completed Returns');
  var range = sheet.getRange(
    4,
    1,
    sheet.getLastRow() - 1,
    sheet.getLastColumn()
  );
  range.sort({ column: 2, ascending: true });
}

function copyData() {}

function userActionRun() {
  copyData();
  AutoSortOnEdit();
}
```

At now you can bind it ti EDIT event

```
function onEdit(){
  userActionRun();
}
```

Comment: Would i write that in order of what events take place first or is that what "function userActionRun" is for?

Comment: So this did not work for me due to my Moving script being event based. i did manage to get it working by combining the 2 scripts.

Comment: Yes, `userActionRun` is a conveyor

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by throwing the 2 scripts together under 1 function like so. I could not figure out how to get the event function to run while calling multiple functions, so I just combined them. Above the 2 "}" brackets is the move Script and below them is the Auto sort.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;

  var actionCol = 24;
  var nameCol = 24;
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();

  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn();

  if (e.value == "TRUE" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Returns");
    if (ss.getSheetByName("Completed Returns")) { 
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Returns");
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber); 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);
      s.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    }
  }
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completed Returns");
    var range = sheet.getRange(4, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 2, ascending: true});
}
```

Thanks Everyone for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Sort`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)) function to sort a data-set.

If you have a function that moves data form one sheet to another when the row is marked as complete, then you can add a line at the end of that to sort it.

You could also create a [FilterView](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681) that sorts the whole sheet based on your parameters. Unlike Filters, FilterViews are saved between sessions.